# Issue adding Excel autofilter in openpyxl program

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

In python I am creating an Excel file using openpyxl, adding a filter and saving it as a new file. The file is created successfully, but throwing the error below when opening. My script:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('Main.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws.auto_filter.ref= 'A1:A51'
ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(0, ['India', 'Japan'], blank=False)
wb.save('results.xlsx')
```

the error screenshot is given below:

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: I suspect `add_fitler_column()` doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: I am able to achieve the task with the help of pandas.

Comment: Same problem and after clicking `OK`, another dialog box opens to say that it has suppressed the auto filters

Comment: openpyxl does not apply the filters (cf [doc](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html)), this shall be done in Excel, what is not convenient actually.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('./Main.xlsx') #./ means, Main.xlsx is in same folder with code.py

#I think first column name is Country

df_india = df[df['Country']=='India']
df_japan = df[df['Country']=='Japan']
frames = [df_india , df_japan]
main_df = pd.concat(frames)
main_df = main_df.reset_index(drop = True)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('results.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
main_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

For more information, check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: No file is been created after running the script.

Comment: This won't add the filter function to the Excel file.

Comment: If you are using Ipython, you should work code cell two times. It's a little bit annoying. If you wrote your code with .py, just open the command prompt and type: python3 code.py